# BottomNavigationBarItem label not showing when selected in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, label, title

Here the code is:

```
 BottomNavigationBar(
  selectedLabelStyle: TextStyles.labelSelectedTextStyle,
  unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyles.labelUnSelectedTextStyle,)
```

Two different styles added for navigation items, but when selected the item label is not showing.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe someone will face the same problem now. Currently class BottomNavigationBar has property **showUnselectedLabels** ,which equals to **false** by default. So to make your labels in BottomNavigationBarItem display, you need to set following property:

```
showUnselectedLabels: true,
```

Answer (score 1):

For this, add the colors separately like below:

```
  selectedLabelStyle: TextStyles.labelSelectedTextStyle,
  unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyles.labelUnSelectedTextStyle,
  selectedItemColor:  Colors.blue,
  unselectedItemColor:  Colors.red,
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been struggling for a long time on this